# Do I change all four coils when I change one spark plug that is faulty

Tags: sparkplugs, buick, ignition-coil, regal

My nephew changed my spark plugs and coils. I have a 2011 Buick Regal and one of the spark plugs blew when I started it, so he removed it and replaced it with an old Prius spark plug. I would like to know, should I change all of the coils? What could possibly cause it? The car doesn’t start immediately like it normally does.

Comment: What do you mean by blew?  It came out of the spark plug hole?  It broke in half?  It just wasn't working?

Comment: What does being a woman have to do with it? Having testicles has no bearing on anyone's ability to understand cars.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! While @GdD could have phrased his statement a little better, I agree. I think what he's trying to say is, we don't charge a "Pink Tax" around here. We are gender neutral in who we help and try to treat everyone the same, regardless. We're glad you're here!

Comment: I apologize to the community and @DeborahReid if that came off too strong, I should have been more constructive with that comment. Regarding the problem, it would be useful to have an understanding of what actually happened. Was there a banging noise? What were the symptoms of the issue? If a spark plug literally blew apart there could be fragments in your engine that could cause serious issues.

Comment: Did the 'new' spark plug which blew out have the same thread size as the original plug?

Comment: There's more to spark plugs than the thread size. Did the 'new' spark plug have the same tip dimensions and heat-retention characteristics as the original?

Answer (score 10):

You shouldn't need to change the spark plug coils unless they are faulty, so the answer to your question is no, you don't need to replace the coils again.

There probably wasn't a need to replace all of the coils in the first place.  Maybe there was an ignition fault that your nephew decided it was just easier to replace all the coils and plugs to fix, but a bit more diagnosis may have identified the faulty coil.

Spark plugs are a service part, since they do wear out.

You really need to tell us what happened to the new spark plug.  If it actually blew out of the spark plug hole, then this would indicate that the threads in the cylinder head that the plugs screw into may be damaged.  If that is the case, then it will likely happen again and will need repairing properly.

Comment: I'm wondering if perhaps the replacement plugs were not the correct type and therefore the threads did not fully engage.

Comment: Meh, with that said, when a coil goes it's not uncommon for others to also start going soon afterwards.  They're usually all from the same batch, made on the same day, they're the same age in the same service conditions in the same vehicle... sometimes it's just a dud, but if it's an older vehicle it's not entirely unexpected to have them all reaching EOL at a similar time.

Comment: Thanks guys the sound was like a pop with white smoke but it didn’t blow out of the spark plug hole thanks so much

Comment: @DeborahReid Did you see where the pop and white smoke came from? Also, was any spray cleaner used while changing the plugs and coils? (I'm thinking that maybe some spray was left somewhere that it could ignite when the engine was started.)